# dreamweaver - autoformat xml within CDATA tags?

Tags: xml, dreamweaver, cdata, autoformatting

I have an xml that contains many CDATA tags which themselves contain an xml document each as a string.

currently these blocks of CDATA are really just this, a string without any formatting.

Is there any way to let dreamweaver auto format/indent those codeblocks within the CDATA tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As those blocks are not XML within the context of the XML document, due to being within the **CDATA** blocks, Dreamweaver has no way of knowing that they can be formatted, not even with the Apply Formatting to selection command.

Unfortunately, the only thing I can suggest within Dreamweaver is to copy and paste the XML content you want formatted into an empty document, then go to Commands -> Apply Source formatting, and then copy and paste the formatted content back into your source document.

I just checked in Aptana 3 and I can select content within a **CDATA** block and go to Source -> Format (CTRL+Shift+F on my windows system). Don't know if the same applies to other Eclipse based applications. So maybe you can do this step in Aptana.